# Show y-axis label kendo ui chart (with angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

[image]I'm trying to plot a bar chart using kendoui + angularjs.

Here is my chart code:

```
<div kendo-chart       
             k-theme="'Flat'"
             k-title="{ text: 'STATUS NFE', visible: true }" 
             k-category-axis="{ labels:{ visible:true }, field: 'os' }"
             k-legend="{ position: 'bottom' }"                 
             k-series-defaults="{ type: 'column'}"                
             k-series="[
                             { field: 'autorizadas', name: 'Autorizadas' },
                             { field: 'canceladas', name: 'Canceladas' },
                             { field: 'nao_enviadas', name: 'Não Enviadas' }
                         ]"                
            k-y-axis="{                                
                            visible: true,
                            format: '{0}',
                            template: 'Notas'
                         }"
             k-data-source="nfeStatus"                    
             k-tooltip="{
                            visible: true,
                            format: '{0}',
                            template: ' #= value # #= series.name #'
                        }"              
             style="height: 400px;" ></div>
```

Everything is working but the y-axis label (that is not appearing).

Some ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Regards.

Comment: I found the solution, but I can't post until the necessary time. I have only used: k-value-axes="[
            {
                title: { text: 'miles'}
            }
        ]"

Answer (score 0):

Bar chart uses value axis instead of y axis so:

Use

```
k-value-axis
```

instead of

```
k-y-axis
```